# Have a null pointer exception in a chat room

Tags: java

first time using overflow so sorry if I'm doing something wrong. But anyway I need help with a chat room project I doing. Simply put the problem I keep having is when I my program I start the server then client then I ask for the name of the user. But right after that I keep getting this error for my client.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at project_pkg2_multiuser_chatroom.CRClient.run(CRClient.java:82)
    at project_pkg2_multiuser_chatroom.CRClient.main(CRClient.java:98)
```

I don't need my whole program done for me just a little help over this hurdle. Thanks I really appreciate it. Oh and if you have any tips for using overflow that might be nice thank you.

```
package project_pkg2_multiuser_chatroom;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

//*This calls all the methods I will be using*
public class CRServer extends JFrame{

    private static final int PORT1 = 10000;
    private static JTextArea jta = new JTextArea("Server Box");
    private static ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static ArrayList<String> passwords = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static HashSet<PrintWriter> writers1 = new HashSet<PrintWriter>();
    private static HashSet<PrintWriter> writers2 = new HashSet<PrintWriter>();
    private static HashSet<PrintWriter> small = new HashSet<PrintWriter>();
    private static ServerSocket listener1;
    private static Socket socket;
    private static FileOutputStream fos;
    private static ObjectOutputStream output;
    private static FileInputStream fis;
    private static ObjectInputStream infrom;
    private static String input;
    private static String user;
    private static String pass;
    private static BufferedReader in;
    private static PrintWriter out;
    private static int numPass;
    private static String  ch = null;
    private static boolean chose = false;

    //*this sets up the UI and starts the handler when the client begins*
    public CRServer() throws IOException {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(jta), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jta.append("Server started at " + new Date() + "\n");    
        setTitle("Server");
        setSize(500, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);   
        System.out.println("The chatroom is running....");
        listener1 = new ServerSocket(PORT1);
        //InetAddress inetAddress = socket.getInetAddress();
        //System.out.println("Client's host name is " + inetAddress.getHostName());
        //System.out.println("Client's IP address is " + inetAddress.getHostAddress());

        try {
            while (true) {
                new Handler(listener1.accept()).start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            listener1.close();
        }
    }

//*This handles the threading*
private static class Handler extends Thread {

    //*this creates the socket for the handler*
    public Handler(Socket s) {
        socket = s;
    }

    //*this runs the thread*
    public synchronized void run() {
        try {

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            fos = new FileOutputStream("users.dat");
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            fis = new FileInputStream("users.dat");
            infrom = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            //*when the client begins this will ask their name*

//            while(true){
//                out.println("ENTERCHANNEL");
//                System.out.println("SUBMITNAME");
//                ch = in.readLine();
//                if(ch == null){
//                    return;
//                } else if (ch == 2){
//                    chose = true;  
//                }
//            }

            while (true) {

                out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                System.out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                user = in.readLine();
                if (user == null) {
                    return;
                }
                else if (!users.contains(user)) {
                    users.add(user);

                    break;
                } else {
                    out.println("NAMETAKEN");
                    System.out.println("NAMETAKEN");
                }
            }
            output.writeObject(users);
            output.close();
            //toClient.writeObject(users);
            out.println("NAMEACCEPTED");
            System.out.println("NAMEACCEPTED");

            users = (ArrayList) infrom.readObject();
            infrom.close();
            //*this will ask their name*
            while (true) {
                out.println("SUBMITPASS");
                System.out.println("SUBMITPASS");
                pass = in.readLine();
                if (pass == null) {
                    return;
                } 
                if(!passwords.contains(pass)) {
                    passwords.add(pass);
                    break;
                }  
                for (int i = 0; i < passwords.size(); i++) {  
                        if (passwords.get(i).equals(pass)) {  
                            int numPass = i;  
                        }  
                    }
                for (int i = 0; i < numPass; i++) {  
                        String name = users.get(i);
                    }
//                if(user == name){
//                    out.println("PASSACCEPTED");
//                }  
            }


            writers1.add(out);

            //*this handler the line the user types in*
//            while (true && chose = false) {
//                input = in.readLine();
//                if (input == null) {
//                    return;
//                }
//                for (PrintWriter whatever : writers1) {
//                    jta.append(user + ": " + input + '\n');
//                    whatever.println("MESSAGE " + user + ": " + input);
//                    System.out.println("MESSAGE");
//                }
//            }   
//            while (true && chose = true) {
//                input = in.readLine();
//                if (input == null) {
//                    return;
//                }
//                for (PrintWriter whatever : writers2) {
//                    jta.append(user + ": " + input + '\n');
//                    whatever.println("MESSAGE " + user + ": " + input);
//                    System.out.println("MESSAGE");
//                }
            /*String line = in.readLine();
            if (users.contains(line)) {
                for (PrintWriter whis : small) {
                    jta.append(user + ": " + input + '\n');
                    whis.println("MESSAGE " + user + ": " + input);
                }    
            }*/
         //}

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        } 
        //*this removes the user once they leave*
        finally {
            if (user != null) {
                users.remove(user);
            }
            if (out != null) {
                writers1.remove(out);
            }
            try {    
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Problem closing socket!");
            }
        }
        //*this updates the binary file which store the users names
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("user.dat");
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            output.writeObject(users);
            output.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CRServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CRServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    }

    //*this is the main method*       
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new CRServer();
    }
}





package project_pkg2_multiuser_chatroom;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

//*This calls all the methods I will be using*
public class CRClient extends JFrame{

    private static int PORT = 10000;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader inList;
    ObjectInputStream inform;
    private static FileInputStream fis;
    private static ObjectInputStream infrom;
    private DataInputStream is = null;
    private static ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Client Box");
    //JFrame mesage = new JFrame("Message");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);
    JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(8, 40 );
    JComboBox userList;

    //*this sets up the UI*
    public CRClient() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        userList = new JComboBox(users.toArray());
        textField.setEditable(false);
        messageArea.setEditable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(userList, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(messageArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                out.println(textField.getText());
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
        /*
        private String getServerAddress() {
            return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Server's IP (It's 127.0.0.1)",
                    "Welcome to the chatroom", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }*/
    private String getChannel() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Select channel",
                "Do you want 1 or 2?", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    //*Allows the user to type in their name*
    private String findName() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Your Screen Name?",
                "Welcome to the chatroom", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    //*Allows the user to type in their password*
//    private String findPassword() {
//        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter Password.",
//                "Welcome to the chatroom", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
//    }

    //*Sets up the thread which the client runs on*
    private void run() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String serverAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, PORT);
        //inform = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            //users = (ArrayList) inform.readObject();

            //*when SUBMITNAME comes in begin send the name the user typed
//            if (line.startsWith("ENTERCHANNEL")){
//                out.println(getChannel());
//            } else 
            if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
                out.println(findName());         //LINE 82
            } else if (line.startsWith("NAMETAKEN")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Error: Name already exists", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
                textField.setEditable(true);
            } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                messageArea.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    //*this is the main method*
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException {
        CRClient client = new CRClient();
        client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXI`enter code here`T_ON_CLOSE);
        client.frame.setVisible(true);
        client.run();        //LINE 98
    }  
}
```

Comment: Which line of your program is 82? A NullPointerException should be easy to solve since you have the line number.

Comment: @takteek He/she has clearly labelled line 82.

Comment: Debug and check if `out` has null value.

Comment: Of course it has null value.  As I pointed out in my answer, it never gets set to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because you didn't set `out` to anything in your `CRClient` object.

Answer (score 0):

The PrintWriter out object is never initialized in client.